# How can I replace a string with XDT transforms

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xdt-transform

My config I want to transform looks like this:

```
<sdfsdfsd>

<blah>
<mypath>D:\my\old\path\aaa</mypath>
</blah>

<blah>
<mypath>D:\my\old\path\bbb</mypath>
</blah>

<blah>
<mypath>D:\my\old\path\ccc</mypath>
</blah>

</sdfsdfsd>
```

All I want to do is replace `D:\my\old\path\<unique value>` with `D:\my\new\path\<unique value>`

I have only seen examples replaces a complete value between <><> or a property inside <>. I just want to do a simple string replace everywhere in the file is this possible?

Comment: You can replace all attributes, but can not replace all values using xdt, [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1). For example `<mypath xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="XPath(//blah/*)" path="D:\h" />` replace all path attributes in mypath elements using XPath. Unfortunately, you can not replace a part of attribute. XSLT transform can replace all elements value, but I'm not sure that it can replace a part of string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<sdfsdfsd>" +
                    "<blah>" +
                    "<mypath>D:\\my\\old\\path\\aaa</mypath>" +
                    "</blah>" +
                    "<blah>" +
                    "<mypath>D:\\my\\old\\path\\bbb</mypath>" +
                    "</blah>" +
                    "<blah>" +
                    "<mypath>D:\\my\\old\\path\\ccc</mypath>" +
                    "</blah>" +
                "</sdfsdfsd>";

            XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);

            foreach(XElement mypath in  element.Descendants("mypath"))
            {
                mypath.SetValue(((string)mypath).Replace("old","new"));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do this programmatically. For all the crazy things XDT transforms can do they must be able to do a simple string replace.

Comment: Instead XLinq it can use immediately xdt transform that has a new elements value...